# What's the safest way to launch an untrusted URL?

Tags: c#, .net

It seems that the generally accepted approach to launch a URL is to call Process.Start, e.g.

```
var url = new Uri(uriString);
Process.Start(url.AbsoluteUri);
```

e.g. this was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129917/what-is-the-best-way-to-launch-a-web-browser-with-a-custom-url-from-a-c-applicat).

The problem with that is that if  the URL is untrusted, bad things can happen.  e.g. if the string is @"c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe", the code above will launch notepad with no questions asked.

OTOH, if you try to launch a local executable like this in the browser, you get plenty of security checks before it happens.

So the question is: how can this be done safely programmatically in a clean way (in C#)?

Not-so-clean techniques we have considered:

- look at the Uri protocol, and block anything that's not http/https.  This is hacky.
- find the registered browser via some reg key, and launch it with the Uri on the cmd line. This type of code tends to be messy and unreliable with some browsers.

So I'm hoping for a technique that would be like a LaunchUrlThroughBrowser(url).

Comment: I know you did not want to do it this way, but here is a solution already considered on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748039/safe-process-start-implementation-for-untrusted-url-strings

Comment: Thanks Joel, I hadn't found this post when I searched. If it comes down to it, I'll use that technique if there is no better way.

Comment: if possible, I will also recommend to launch the browser using a different user a/c having low privileges (use ProcessStartInfo for passing user credentials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no great way to do this, short of manual filtering the URL, as explained in [Safe Process.Start implementation for untrusted URL strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748039/safe-process-start-implementation-for-untrusted-url-strings).  So that might just be the way to go.